# How to make the row and column in the cneter of div?

Tags: html, css

The below code shows 3 columns on the left of the page, how to make these columns in the center?

css file

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

html file

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't need to use floats for layouts anymore - they should only be used for their original purpose for letting text flow around an image.  [More about floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex layout for this by adding `display: flex` to the row container. By specifying `justify-content: center` all flex items will be centered inside the flex container.

You can also avoid that `float` stuff which is not intended for box layouts but for text and images.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  width: 12%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more infos on flex check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox and the very handy cheat sheet here
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with the following code

```css
.column {
  width: 12%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any exact reason why you want to use

```
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: the row after clears the float - now you've changed to flex you should also remove the float

Answer (score 0):

Flex is all you need. Just add the following to your css:

```css
    .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
```